# How to implement the 0.5*||euclidean_norm||^2?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gradient, euclidean-distance

I want to use the Euclidean norm as loss function 0.5 ||Correlation||^2. But, If I implement it, not the correct result appears. It should come out left or right input image again.

I implemented two gradients. The `grad` spits out the left or right image, while `grad_norm` (Euclidean Distance) does spit out very large numbers...

```
import tensorflow as tf

im1 = np.ascontiguousarray(np.arange(36).reshape((1,3,3,4))).astype(np.float32)
im2 = np.ascontiguousarray(np.arange(36,72).reshape((1,3,3,4))).astype(np.float32)
t_mult = tf.multiply(t_im1, t_im2)
t_corr = tf.reduce_sum(t_mult, axis=[1])
grad = tf.gradients(ys=t_corr, xs=[t_im1, t_im2])

# Euclidiean Norm:  1/2 ||t_corr||^2 = df/im0 = im1
loss1 = tf.multiply(tf.square(t_corr), 0.5)
grad_norm = tf.gradients(ys=loss1, xs=[t_im1, t_im2], stop_gradients=[t_im1, t_im2])
loss1 = tf.multiply(tf.square(t_corr), 0.5)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# print t_mult.eval()
# print t_corr.eval()
# print grad0[0].eval() # returns right image
# print grad0[1].eval() # returns left image

grad_norm[0].eval() # ought to return left image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code behaves right, you have a theoretical problem.

1. `t_mult` is the element-wise product of ***im1*** and ***im2***. Clearly, δ***( im1 * im2 )***/δ***im2*** will indeed yield ***im1***, so `tf.gradiens( t_mult, t_im2 )` would yield `im1`.
2. When you apply `tf.reduce_sum()`, so basically you add up all the elements along an axis, this does not change, because `tf.gradiens()` takes the *partial derivative* and the full sum only changes with each element of `im1`. Therefore `grad = tf.gradients( t_corr, t_im2 )` also yields `im1`.
3. When you take the square, however, the situation changes. Since you're squaring the **sum of elements along an axis**, there will be interaction between them, you will not only get squared terms but cross products of each pair. This will add in a bunch of linear terms along the square, and when you take the derivative, you will not only get δ***x<sup>2</sup>***/δ***x*** = 2***x*** but a lot of other terms with interactions between elements.
4. The true problem is in this line: `# Euclidiean Norm:  1/2 ||t_corr||^2 = df/im0 = im1` because the real formula for the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) is √Σ***x***<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>. But that won't yield the clean `im0` either, because if you take the square root, you will have interactions again. If you want to get back `im0` you need to calculate `loss1 = tf.reduce_sum( 0.5 * tf.square( t_mult ), axis = 1 )` and once you take the derivative, you have to divide by the square of the other image. Not sure what you're trying to achieve but this code (tested):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

im1 = np.ascontiguousarray(np.arange(36).reshape((1,3,3,4))).astype(np.float32)
t_im1 = tf.constant( im1 )
im2 = np.ascontiguousarray(np.arange(36,72).reshape((1,3,3,4))).astype(np.float32)
t_im2 = tf.constant( im2 )
t_mult = tf.multiply( t_im1, t_im2 )
t_corr = tf.reduce_sum(t_mult, axis=[1])
grad = tf.gradients( ys=t_corr, xs= t_im2, name = "grad" )

# Euclidiean Norm:  0.5 * sqrt( sum( ||t_mult||^2 ) ) = d f/d im1 = im2
loss1 = tf.reduce_sum( 0.5 * tf.square( t_mult ), axis = 1 )
grad_norm = tf.gradients( ys = loss1, xs = t_im1, name = "grad_norm" ) / t_im2 ** 2

with tf.Session() as sess:
    fetch = [ t_im1, grad[ 0 ], grad_norm[ 0 ] ]
    res = sess.run( fetch )
    for idx, v in enumerate( res ):
        print( " =========================")
        print( fetch[ idx ].name )
        print()
        print( v )
```

will output:

> =========================
>   Const:0
>
> [[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>      [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>      [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]]
>
> [[12. 13. 14. 15.]
>      [16. 17. 18. 19.]
>      [20. 21. 22. 23.]]
>
> [[24. 25. 26. 27.]
>      [28. 29. 30. 31.]
>      [32. 33. 34. 35.]]]]
>    =========================
>   grad/Mul_grad/Mul_1:0
>
> [[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>      [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>      [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]]
>
> [[12. 13. 14. 15.]
>      [16. 17. 18. 19.]
>      [20. 21. 22. 23.]]
>
> [[24. 25. 26. 27.]
>      [28. 29. 30. 31.]
>      [32. 33. 34. 35.]]]]
>    =========================
>   strided_slice:0
>
> [[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>      [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>      [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]]
>
> [[12. 13. 14. 15.]
>      [16. 17. 18. 19.]
>      [20. 21. 22. 23.]]
>
> [[24. 25. 26. 27.]
>      [28. 29. 30. 31.]
>      [32. 33. 34. 35.]]]]